# How to print triangle using '*' in Python?

Tags: python, numbers, integer

Like:

```
          *
        * * *
      * * * * *
      ----n=5----
```

Note: Where n will user input in odd integer number.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over line numbers from `0` to the ceil of `n / 2` and then center two times the line number plus one stars.

```
n = 5
for l in range(n//2+1):
    print(' '.join(['*'] * (l*2+1)).center(n*2))
```

which gives:

```
    *     
  * * *   
* * * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def asterisk_triangle(n):
    """
    takes an integer n and then returns an
    asterisk triangle consisting of (n) many columns
    """
    x = 1
    while (x <= (n+1)/2):
        space = int((n+1)/2-x)
        print(" " *space*2, end='')
        print("* " * (2*x-1))
        x = x + 1

    return

# call asterisk_triangle function here
# here n=9
asterisk_triangle(9)
```

**Output:**

```
        * 
      * * * 
    * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: that's the answer to the question or additional information to the question?